# $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+iy)=0$ for every $y \in (-1,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $\Omega=\{x+iy:-1<y<1\}$, $f \in H(\Omega)$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Prove that 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+iy)=0
\end{equation*} for every $y \in (-1,1)$. Furthermore, is it true that the limit is uniform if $y \in [-\alpha,\alpha]$ for $\alpha<1$?

Comment: I don't have an obvious counterexample, but this "must" be false. It's true if you assume more about $f$, for example if you assume $f$ is _bounded_ (hint: Montel).

Comment: @David C. Ullrich. If I assume that $|f|<1$, then how do we use Montel's theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Counterexample:

Let
$$f(z)=e^{-e^{2z}}.$$

Then $$|f(x+iy)|=e^{-e^{2x}\cos(2y)},$$so $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$but $$|f(x+i\pi/4)|=1.$$

### Correct Version:

It's true for bounded $f$.

Hint, *assuming* that $f$ is *bounded*:

Say $f(x)\to0$ but $f(x+iy_0)\not\to0$ as $x\to+\infty$. Since $f$ is bounded there exist $x_n\to+\infty$ and $a\ne0$ such that $$f(x_n+iy_0)\to a\quad(n\to\infty).$$
Let $$f_n(z)=f(z+x_n).$$ By Montel there exists a holomorphic function $g$ and a sequence $n_j$ such that $f_{n_j}\to g$ uniformly on compact sets. It follows that $g(x)=0$, for all real $x$ but $g(iy_0)=a$, contradiction

Comment: Yes, I got it now. I think the boundedness of $f$ is a "MUST".

Comment: @KKWong Boundedness is certainly needed for this argument. We need a counterexample to show that it's required for the result to hold...

Comment: But it is also true that the convergence is uniform on $y \in [-\alpha,\alpha]$ if $f$ is kept to be bounded?

Comment: @KKWong Yes, that's also true. With more or less the same proof...

Comment: @KKWong Got it...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich can you say a word or two about how you arrived at this counterexample? Thank you.

Comment: @qbert If I had something useful to say about how I found that example I'd let you know; alas I really can't say anything very specific - tried a lot of things, one worked.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich fair enough, thank you for your response. Also, I really enjoyed your book on complex analysis